# linker error unresolved external symbol taglib nuget visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, nuget, taglib

I have installed Taglibcpp library using nuget package manager in visual studio 2019. When I try to build the project, I get the following errors:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl TagLib::FileName::FileName(char const *)" (??0FileName@TagLib@@QEAA@PEBD@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *)" (??0MainWindow@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)
>
> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl TagLib::FileRef::FileRef(class TagLib::FileName,bool,enum TagLib::AudioProperties::ReadStyle)" (??0FileRef@TagLib@@QEAA@VFileName@1@_NW4ReadStyle@AudioProperties@1@@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *)" (??0MainWindow@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)

Comment: Looks like you did not link to the library for taglib.

Comment: so how to link, I thought that nuget automatically link to libraries

Comment: I think it sets up the paths but does not link to individual libraries in every project that you have. The automatic ones probably use #pragma comment(lib, libname.lib) in a header.